# python 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add form to my django view. The problem is, I cannot declare class. That is the problem:

[image]

`Addform.py`:

```
from django import forms

class AddSubjectForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self):
    pass

name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

`Views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from AddSubject.AddForm import AddSubjectForm

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('AddSubject/index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddSubjectForm()
        context = Context({
                       'form': form,
                       })
    else:
        form = AddSubjectForm()
            context = Context({        
                       'form': form,
                       })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And finally I recieve error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/AddSubject/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'AddSubject')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "blablabla\AddSubject\views.py" in index
14.         form = AddSubjectForm()

Exception Type: TypeError at /AddSubject/
Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable
```

I was looking for solution in Google, but every response was about filenames. It does not work for me :/ Have you got any idea, why AddSubjectForm doesn't work?

Comment: (a) I assume the incorrect indentation is a result of copy-and-pasting here, not a problem with your actual code. (b) Can you please paste the entire error here, not just a part of it?

Comment: `__init__` in `AddSubjectForm` should be indent.

Comment: The code you've pasted wouldn't give that error. Are you sure you haven't defined or imported something else called `AddSubjectForm` somewhere?

Comment: Your import could be wrong `from AddSubject.AddForm import AddSubjectForm` should be `from AddForm import AddSubjectForm`.

Comment: @limelights - you're right! This import is correct, and everything works fine ;) thank you.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer with some explanation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import statement is wrong as per my comment.

What you've written is

```
from AddSubject.AddForm import AddSubjectForm
```

change it to

```
from AddFrom import AddSubjectForm
```

What using `from` does is traverse the ALL modules so that it can import from a relative module. But since `AddSubject` isn't a package within `AddSubject` it loads from a module instead and treats the package as a module.

A good read is found here: [Simple Statements#import](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import)